# How do I specify partial file paths in css so I can change file locations in just one place

Tags: html, css

I'm sort of new to HTML and I  have the code:

```
<video controls loop  id=hgt autoplay>
  <source src="Covers/Cover 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I need to be able to substitute the partial file path "Covers" so I don't have to change every pathname reference in my code every time I move files around on my system.

Comment: This isn't possible with vanilla HTML.  Is your HTML completely static or are you using a framework?  You could potentially insert the file path dynamically with JS but this would be serious overkill just to save you some typing.  Any decent IDE would allow you to change that path easily with search and replace.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for your hrlp